# Problem with aligning result with the input field

Tags: css

I centerd aligned my input field bu using

```
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  margin : 0 auto;
}
```

But I can not align my autosuggest results with the input field.
You can check my work from the link below
[My Design](https://fullformsite.com/live-search/)

Comment: It looks well, describe your expectation

Answer (score 0):

`margin-bottom` is being added to the textbox somehow. Either remove it, or add `!important` to your css.

```
input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  margin : 0 auto !important;
}
```